# Can't connect via sftp to a server with GUI Clients, but terminal works

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp

Yesterday I was able to connect to a server via sftp with FileZilla without any problems. Today I always get a timeout while trying to connect.

I tried using the network wizzard in FileZilla and found out there's an IP mismatch, so I set the IP FileZilla found manually which just caused to error to change to a port mismatch.

Other Clients like Cyberduck don't work either. Using the sftp command in the terminal works fine tho

I'm on MacOS Monterey 12.1 with an M1 Macbook.
I updated to Monterey yesterday, this was before installing FileZilla tho, so I don't think that's the problem

FileZilla Errors:
[image: Timeout error]

[image: IP Mismatch]

Comment: What do you mean by "IP mismatch"?

Comment: When I test the connection with FileZilla via Network configuration Wizzard it throws a "Response 510 Mismatch: Your IP is ... Wrong External IP address"

Comment: Please add some screenshots so we can see the same things you do.

Comment: edited question

Comment: Not sure these two issues are related, do you have another FTP server you could try connecting to? Anyway, if you click on "next" in the dialog of the second screenshot, it offers two ways to resolve this. Did you try those?

Comment: I don't have another ftp to test on. As stated in the Original question, I tried providing the IP manually, this just causes FileZilla to throw a "Response 502 Port mismatch. Command has been tainted by router or firewall" instead. The weird thing is tho, as already stated as well, that I can connect via sftp command in the terminal without any issues, it's just clients like filezilla where I face this issue.

Comment: The issue is that the check for external IP address provides a IP in the private range so that is not your external IP. Either your router is not returning the correct info or you internet provider is doing something. Can you turn the firewall and router check off in filezilla

Comment: Can you try to reinstall Filezilla? It asked for some permissions when I installed it, maybe they got lost when upgrading to Monterey.

Comment: See https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/3045 for info - that thread suggests that the test is to find misconfigured routers and firewalls

Comment: @mmmmmm where exactly can I disable this?

Comment: I also don't think the issue is the router, as I can connect to servers on my Windows machine without issues

Comment: If Cyberduck doesn't work either, the problem is most likely not the router configuration. As said, please delete and reinstall one of the GUI applications and try again.

Comment: Your machines are on the private network so the IP does match - the other servers are on the internet. Fixing this depends on the router

Comment: @nohillside Uninstalled both and reinstalled Filezilla, didn't fix the issue

Comment: @mmmmmm how come other machines work fine tho? Shouldn't the router fail for every other device as well?

Comment: You need to be more exact on what other machines work and don't work - what network are the machines on. If on the same private network as the mac then it should be OK - if on another then the router alters things Whjat is the IP address of the working machines

Comment: The other machines are connected to the same router as my mac. Yesterday my mac was able to connect via sftp as well while being connected to said router.

Comment: So I managed to connect to other SFTPs server from here https://www.sftp.net/public-online-sftp-servers via FileZilla. This kinda left me with the thought that maybe my IP was banned from the server I can't connect to. But since I'm able to connect via terminal, this makes no sense either